# Android resizing large image recieved as base64 string

Tags: android, image, base64, bitmapfactory

i have some issue resizing an image in android.
i have a base64 string (i don't have a file or a url, just the string) and so far i get a out of memory exception as soon as i try to decode it.

```
public String resizeBase64Image(String base64image){

    byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(base64image,Base64.DEFAULT); //out of memory exception...

    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length,options);

    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);
    byte [] newbytes=baos.toByteArray();

    return Base64.encodeToString(newbytes, Base64.DEFAULT);

}
```

Does anybody have an idea?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

it took me a while to come back to this project but i finally found a solution to my issue. 
first, i needed to modify the application tag of the Manfest to add largeHeap=:true":

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:largeHeap="true" >
```

Making use of the garbage collector helped a lot.

```
public String resizeBase64Image(String base64image){
    byte [] encodeByte=Base64.decode(base64image.getBytes(),Base64.DEFAULT); 
    BitmapFactory.Options options=new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inPurgeable = true;
    Bitmap image = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(encodeByte, 0, encodeByte.length,options);


    if(image.getHeight() <= 400 && image.getWidth() <= 400){
        return base64image;
    }
    image = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(image, IMG_WIDTH, IMG_HEIGHT, false);

    ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
    image.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, baos);

    byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
    System.gc();
    return Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.NO_WRAP);

}
```

Comment: Which xml file are you talking about. Android has many xml files so please specify. Am an android developer but I have weakness in dealing with bitmaps. Am looking for tutorials where I can learn the whole theory the hard way. Do you know of any?

Comment: Hi Karue. The xml file is the Manifest. i updated the post with an example. Unfortunately, i don't know any tutorial but please note that this approach may not be the best if you are looking to just load and scale down an image from your Drawable. Android provide a more efficent way to load large bitmap from the resources : https://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html

Answer (score 0):

In the case of OutOfMemoryError, below code may be helpful.

```
public String BitMapToString(Bitmap bitmap){
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
        bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,100, baos);
        byte [] b=baos.toByteArray();
        String temp=null;
        try{
        System.gc();
        temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }catch(OutOfMemoryError e){
            baos=new  ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG,50, baos);
            b=baos.toByteArray();
            temp=Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
            Log.e("EWN", "Out of memory error catched");
        }
        return temp;
  }
```

Basically what i did is : i catch OutofMemoryError and in that catch block i resize it by 50% and then i encode it to string.

Answer (score -1):

Try this.

```
options.inSampleSize = 2;
```